# uppercase to lowercase and vice versa

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase

this code should convert uppercase to lowercase and vice versa .. the problem is its returning both 
upper and lower .. for example when i enter the word "tuna" it returns "TUNAtuna" .. help please

```
string rev_letter(string s)
{
    string word = s;
    string final_word="";
    char c;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<=(word.length()-1);i++)
    {
    c=word.at(i);
    if(isupper(c))
    {
        putchar(tolower(c));
        final_word+=c;
    }
    else
    {
        putchar(toupper(c));
        final_word+=c;
    }

    }
    return final_word;
}
```

Comment: Please, state the language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `putchar`, you print the character as you expect (to the screen) but you *don't* put the character into `final_word`. In final_word, you actually put the initial word.

Try this:

```
string rev_letter(string s)
{
    string word = s;
    string final_word="";
    char c;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<(word.length());i++)
    {
       c=word.at(i);
       if(isupper(c))
       {
           final_word+=tolower(c);
       }
       else
       {
           final_word+=toupper(c);
       }
    }

    return final_word;
}
```

Comment: @user2786906 You should "accept" the answer if you believe it answers to your question. This way, people will know it is solved.